# Encryption type requested is not supported by the KDC

Tags: windows, security, authentication, kerberos, windows-11

I am having intermittent issues with RDP'ing from a Windows 11 Enterprise PC to another Windows 11 Enterpise PC.

Both PC's are domain joined and on the same subnet.

Both PC's have a GPO applied to enforce:

**Require use of specific security layer for remote (RDP) connections' is set to 'Enabled: SSL'**

**Require user authentication for remote connections by using Network Level Authentication' is set to 'Enabled'**

**Set client connection encryption level' is set to 'Enabled: High Level'**

This is the error I get when RDPing. Rebooting the remote PC fixes this sometimes. I do not get this error when RDP'ing from a different Windows 10 Enterprise PC at a different site that is authenticating to a different Domain Controller.

[[image: RDP Error][1]]

This is the negotiation captured by wireshark when the failure occurs.

[image: Wireshark Fail]

This is the response captured by wireshark when the failure occurs.

[image: Wireshark Fail Response]

This is the request captured by wireshark when the connection succeeds.

[image: Wireshark Success]

This is the response captured by wireshark when the connection succeeds.

[image: Wireshark Success 2]

If anyone could point me in the right direction or what to look at I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have a capture of the Kerberos requests (on udp&tcp port 88)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The november security updates introduced bugs in kerberos that may be the reason for this behavior. You should install the out-of-band updates on your DCs that are meant to correct those. I had similar RDP problems that were solved by installing the updates. See https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/november-2022-out-of-band-update-released-take-action/ba-p/3680144

Comment: Looks like we are missing that KB. Going to install it and test to see if that is the issue. Thank you

Comment: This seems to have fixed my issue along with a couple other problems I was experiencing. Thank you again!